# Key lookup still happening after creating covering index

Tags: sql-server, bookmark-lookup, covering-index

I've implemented a covering index to avoid a key lookup:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_StatusHistory_Covering ON StatusHistory(ID) 
       INCLUDE (Status_ID, StatusComment, StatusReason_ID,
       StatusReasonComment, UserEnteredStatusDateTime, 
       ChangeDateTime, ChangedBy_UserName, IMWBWagonMass) 
       WITH (ONLINE= ON)
```

But the key lookup is still happening.

[image: Key Lookup]

[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hk9ilXHNI)

Here is the query causing this:

```
DECLARE @default_tare DECIMAL(18,2) = 19.94
SELECT      TOP 100  *,         
        [Gross (WI)] -  ISNULL([Tare (WX)],@default_tare) AS [Arrived Nett (WI-WX)],
        [Gross (WN)] - ISNULL([Tare (WT)],@default_tare) AS  [Tipped Nett (WN-WT)],         
        [Client Weight] - ([Gross (WI)] -  ISNULL([Tare (WX)],@default_tare)) AS [Arrived Variance],            
        [Client Weight] - ([Gross (WN)] - ISNULL([Tare (WT)],@default_tare)) AS [Tipped Variance]

FROM        (SELECT     CASE WHEN LoadedWeight > 9999 THEN LoadedWeight/1000 ELSE LoadedWeight END [Client Weight]
                    ,CASE WHEN his.Status_Code IN ('WH','WI') THEN his.IMWBWagonMass END AS [Gross (WI)]
                    ,CASE WHEN his.Status_Code ='WN' THEN his.IMWBWagonMass END AS [Gross (WN)]
                    ,CASE WHEN his.Status_Code = 'WX' THEN his.[IMWBWagonMass] ELSE NULL END AS [Tare (WX)]                 
                    ,CASE WHEN his.Status_Code = 'WT' THEN his.[IMWBWagonMass] ELSE NULL END AS [Tare (WT)]
                    ,dp.Description AS Commodity
                    ,dp.Grade                       
                    ,Header_Client_Name AS Client
                    ,Header_Destination_Name AS Destination
                    ,Header_Origin_Name AS Origin
                    ,Header_Product_Name AS [Commodity Name]
                    ,Header_ProductSubCategory_Name AS [Commodity Group]
                    ,his.StatusComment AS [Status Comment]
                    ,LEFT(LOWER(Rcd.Header_LastUpdatedByUser_UserName),CASE WHEN Header_LastUpdatedByUser_UserName <>'System' THEN CHARINDEX( '@',Rcd.Header_LastUpdatedByUser_UserName)-1 ELSE 999 END) AS [Last updated by]
                    ,ISNULL(Header_StatusDateTime, Header_CreatedDateTime) AS [Last Updated]
                    ,st.Name  AS [Status Name]
                    ,StatusReasonComment AS [Reason Comment]
                    ,StatusReasonName AS [Reason Name]
                    ,UserEnteredStatusDateTime AS [Status Actual Event Time]
                    ,ChangeDateTime AS [Status System Change Time]
                    ,ChangedBy_UserName AS [Status Changed by]
                    ,st.Code  AS [Status Code]
                    ,sr.Code AS [Reason Code]
                    ,his.ID AS [Status History ID]
                    ,his.StatusReasonDateTime  AS [Reason Time]
                    ,his.IMWBWagonMass AS [Wagon Status History Mass]
                    ,rcd.ID AS [Wagon Line ID]
                    ,Wagon_Number AS [Wagon Number]
                    ,GrossWeight AS [Gross (Most Recent)]
                    ,TareWeight AS [Tare (Most Recent)]
                    ,Tarps
                    ,DelayDescription AS [Delay Description]
                    ,rcd.StatusComment AS [Current Wagon Status Comment]
                    ,rcd.StatusDateTime AS [Current Wagon Status Date Time]
                    ,rcd.Status_Code AS [Current Wagon Status Code]
                    ,rcd.Status_Name AS [Current Wagon Status]
                    ,RailConsignment_ID
                    ,Header_Number AS [Consignment]
                    ,Header_DepartureFromClientDateTime AS [Departure Time]
                    ,Header_EstimatedArrivalDateTime AS [Estimated Arrival Time]
                    ,Header_IsInbound
                    ,Header_PermitNumber AS [Permit Nr]
                    ,Header_RailAccountNumber AS [Rail Account Nr]
                    ,Header_Sender_Name AS [Sender]
                    ,Header_SenderSidingNumber AS [Sender Siding Nr]
                    ,Header_Status_Code AS [Train Current Status Code]
                    ,Header_Status_Name AS [Train Current Status]
                    ,Header_StatusDateTime AS [Train Current Status Actual Event Time]
                    ,Header_Train AS [Train]
                    ,Header_CreatedDateTime AS [Created On]
                    ,rcd.dw_timestamp
                    ,CreatedDateTime AS [Wagon Created On]
                    ,Header_Contract_Number AS [Contract Nr]
                    ,rcd.IMWBWagonMass AS [Wagon Mass (Most Recent)]
                    ,Header_WeeklyRailPlan_ID AS [NWB ID]
                    ,NettWeight AS [Nett (Most Recent)]
                    ,CASE WHEN rcd.Status_Code = 'WA' THEN rcd.Header_StatusDateTime ELSE Header_WAChangeDateTime END AS [Wagons Uncoupled From Locomotive]
                    ,CASE WHEN rcd.Status_Code = 'WF' THEN rcd.Header_StatusDateTime ELSE Header_WFChangeDateTime END AS [Consignment Finalised]
                    ,CASE WHEN rcd.Status_Code = 'WG' THEN rcd.Header_StatusDateTime ELSE Header_WGChangeDateTime END AS [Consignment at the Gate]
        FROM        RailConsignmentDetails AS  rcd WITH(NOLOCK)
        JOIN        FullStatusHistoryRailLine AS his WITH(NOLOCK) on his.ID = rcd.ID
        JOIN        DimProduct AS dp WITH(NOLOCK) ON dp.ID = rcd.Header_Product_ID
        LEFT JOIN   DimConsignmentStatus AS st  WITH(NOLOCK)ON st.ID = his.Status_ID
        LEFT JOIN   DimStatusReasons   AS sr WITH(NOLOCK)  ON st.ID = his.StatusReason_ID
        WHERE       Header_Deleted = 0
        AND         rcd.Deleted = 0
        AND         ISNULL(Header_StatusDateTime, Header_CreatedDateTime) BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND GETDATE()+ 1) AS t
```

The FullStatusHistoryLine view is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[FullStatusHistoryRailLine]
    AS
        SELECT      sh.PK,
                    sh.ID,
                    CAST(sh.Number AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Number,
                    sh.Status_ID,
                    sh.Status_Name,
                    sh.StatusComment,
                    sh.StatusReason_ID,
                    sh.StatusReasonComment,
                    dsr.Name AS StatusReasonName,
                    sh.UserEnteredStatusDateTime,
                    sh.ChangeDateTime,
                    sh.ChangedBy_Id,
                    sh.ChangedBy_UserName,
                    sh.dw_timestamp,
                    dcs.code AS Status_Code,
                    sh.StatusReason_Code,                       
                    prev.StatusReasonDateTime AS FromStatusReasonDateTime,
                    sh.StatusReasonDateTime,
                    sh.IMWBWagonMass
        FROM        StatusHistory AS sh
        INNER JOIN  DimConsignmentStatus AS dcs ON sh.Status_ID = dcs.ID
        LEFT JOIN   DimStatusReasons AS dsr ON dsr.ID = sh.StatusReason_ID
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 StatusReasonDateTime 
                    FROM    StatusHistory
                    WHERE   ID = sh.ID
                    AND     Number = sh.Number
                    AND     IsHeader = sh.IsHeader
                    AND     TransportMode_Name = sh.TransportMode_Name
                    AND     StatusReasonDateTime < sh.StatusReasonDateTime
                    ORDER BY StatusReasonDateTime DESC) AS prev
        WHERE       sh.TransportMode_Name = 'Rail'
        AND         sh.IsHeader = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      CAST(rcd.ID AS VARCHAR) + '_' + CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64),rcd.StatusReasonDateTime,126),CONVERT(VARCHAR(64),rcd.LastUpdatedDateTime,126)) AS VARCHAR) + '_L' AS PK,
                    rcd.ID,
                    CAST(rcd.Wagon_Number AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Number,
                    rcd.Status_ID,
                    rcd.Status_Name,
                    rcd.StatusComment,
                    rcd.StatusReason_ID,
                    '' AS StatusReasonComment,
                    rcd.StatusReason_Name AS StatusReasonName,
                    rcd.StatusDateTime AS UserEnteredStatusDateTime,
                    rcd.StatusSavedDateTime AS ChangeDateTime,
                    rcd.LastUpdatedByUser_Id AS ChangedBy_Id,
                    rcd.LastUpdatedByUser_UserName AS ChangedBy_UserName,
                    rcd.dw_timestamp,
                    rcd.Status_Code,
                    rcd.StatusReason_Code,
                    prev.StatusReasonDateTime AS FromStatusReasonDateTime,
                    rcd.StatusReasonDateTime,
                    rcd.IMWBWagonMass
        FROM        RailConsignmentDetails AS rcd
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 StatusReasonDateTime 
                    FROM    StatusHistory AS sh
                    WHERE   sh.ID = rcd.ID
                    AND     Number =  CAST(rcd.Wagon_Number AS VARCHAR(255))
                    AND     IsHeader = 0
                    AND     TransportMode_Name = 'Rail'
                    AND     StatusReasonDateTime < rcd.Header_StatusReasonDateTime
                    ORDER BY StatusReasonDateTime DESC) AS prev
```

And finally the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StatusHistory](
[PK] [varchar](99) NOT NULL,
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Number] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Status_ID] [int] NULL,
[Status_Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[StatusComment] [varchar](255) NULL,
[StatusReason_ID] [int] NULL,
[StatusReasonComment] [varchar](255) NULL,
[UserEnteredStatusDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ChangeDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ChangedBy_Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[ChangedBy_UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
[IsHeader] [bit] NOT NULL,
[dw_timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EventTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[StatusReason_Code] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[StatusReasonDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[TransportMode_Name] [varchar](5) NULL,
[IMWBWagonMass] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[RoadFirstWeight] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[RoadSecondWeight] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[DraftSurveyTons] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[StatusHistory_key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [XPK_StatusHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[StatusHistory_key] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: In the Key-Lookup popup, if you see "Predicates" or "Seek Predicates", you have to add those columns as “Key Columns” (not as include) to your index to fully cover and address the missing indexed-columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Seek Predicate on `StatusHistory`:

> Seek Predicates Seek Keys[1]: Prefix:
>
> [GrindrodTerminalsDW].[dbo].[StatusHistory].ID,
>
> [GrindrodTerminalsDW].[dbo].[StatusHistory].TransportMode_Name,
>
> [GrindrodTerminalsDW].[dbo].[StatusHistory].IsHeader
>
> Scalar Operator([GrindrodTerminalsDW].[dbo].[RailConsignmentDetails].[ID] as
>   [rcd].[ID]), Scalar Operator('Rail'), Scalar Operator((0))

You have to add TransportMode_Name and IsHeader columns to your new index so that it will really become covering:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_StatusHistory_Covering ON StatusHistory
(ID, TransportMode_Name, IsHeader) 
INCLUDE (Status_ID, StatusComment, StatusReason_ID,
       StatusReasonComment, UserEnteredStatusDateTime, 
       ChangeDateTime, ChangedBy_UserName, IMWBWagonMass) 
WITH (ONLINE= ON)
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out earlier and it did indeed sort out the issue